# Replacing Rails form fields

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm learning RoR and 'mapping' a form's textboxes to a data model's fields that are of type string is straightforward like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  ....
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, I have a field of datetime type (dob) and the default form controls consist of five dropdown lists which I don't like so I want to use the foundation-datetimepicker-rails gem found [here](https://github.com/aliibrahim/foundation-datetimepicker-rails).

The original code that scaffolding produced for a datetime type was the following:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :dob %><br>
  <%= f.datetime_select :dob %>
</div>
```

However, how can I replace the above to work with something like the javascript control below to display the control and link it to the dob field:

```
<input class="datetimepicker" type="text" >
<script type="text/javascript">$('.datetimepicker').fdatetimepicker()</script>
```

**UPDATE**: Following Mike Desjardins' answer below, the datetimepicker is functional and is displayed, however, it sits on top of existing content. From the screenshots below, the datetimepicker is currently on top of the:

```
<%= f.label :company_id %>
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :date, :class => 'datetimepicker' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_id %><br>
    <%= f.select(:company_id, Company.order("name").map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contact %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :contact %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <%= link_to "home", root_path, { :class=>"button expand" } %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.datetimepicker').fdatetimepicker();
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

*original view*

[image: original view]

*current view*

[image: current view]

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :dob %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :dob, :class => 'datetimepicker' %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker').fdatetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That sort of works in that the datetimepicker is functional and on display. However, it currently sits on top of other content and is not 'inline' as explained in my updated original post.

Comment: Hrm, that looks like it might be a limitation of the foundation date time picker, unfortunately. :/